# Detect when multiple elements are at top of browser screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the setup, I have multiple divs on a page which are full widths and have blocks of color. The number of divs can vary from page to page. Each div with have a class associated to it (light or dark) and I have a logo pinned to the top of the browser window.

What I am trying to accomplish is this. I want to detect when each on of these div (with a common class) reach the top of the browser window. I then want to see if it has a light or dark class (only this div that just reached the top.) and then change the logo on the page depending on that value.

The closest thing I have come across is some onscreen jquery plugins that will add an :onscreen value to the current div that is on the screen. This would be great if I could only add this onscreen attribute when it reaches the top rather than just into view.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how one might accomplish this?

```
// jsfiddle example
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UhrrR/

Comment: can you create a demo please

Comment: A simple HTML/CSS demo?

Comment: Yes in jsfiddle.net so the community can rapidly help you.

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UhrrR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, I was just looking at a library that does this very thing:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

You can add listeners to your elements that will fire off when your element hits the top of the viewport:

```
$('#myDiv').waypoint(function() {
  var color = $(this).css('background-color');
  $('img.logo').attr('src', 'logo.png');
});
```

For an amazing demo of it in use:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/16/on-scroll-header-effects/

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Chris Hardie that Waypoints is the way to go. I built a simple example based on your description.

https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints

http://codepen.io/cgspicer/pen/FrCgI

Comment: Here's a fork of your jsfiddle using a similar approach as the codepen I built: http://jsfiddle.net/tXwD8/1/

Comment: agreed, thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZaeT/), I've used my own, because I've started before you posted your fiddle, but the idea is pretty the same.

I have a position of a `logo` element, and when scroll happens I check whether one of the desired blocks intersects logo block. On success a class from a custom `data-trigger-class` attribute is assigned to a `logo` element.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this.